# How to efficiently loop images in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make an app that needs looping of images like in a Slot machine. I have the images in the order that they need to loop, and later when a button is pressed they'll need to stop at some position.
I know I can use QPixmap and redraw at a specified interval, although I am pretty sure there's a more efficient way of doing it. What I want to do is to loop the images infinitely with constant speed, and once the button is pressed I will calculate at which image to stop, start slowing down the animation and stop at the predefined index in x seconds.
I think that the Qt Animation Framework can be used here. I am just not sure how to make the infinite loop.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simplified version of a code that I wrote :

It is a widget that display animated texts and almost what you want.

```
class Labels : public QFrame {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY( int offset READ offset WRITE setOffset )
public:
    /* The property used to animate the view */
    int off;
    QStringList texts;
    Label() : QFrame() {
        texts << "text 1" << "text 2" << "text 3" << "text 4";
        setFixedSize( 200, 200 );
    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) {
        QPainter painter( this );
        int x = 20;
        int y = 20;
        foreach( QString str, texts ) {
            int y1 = y + off;
            /* Used to draw the texts as a loop */
            /* If texts is underneath the bottom, draw at the top */
            if ( y1 > height() ) { 
                y1 -= height();
            }
            painter.drawText( x, y1, str );
            y+= 50;
        }
    }

    int offset() {
        return off;
    }

    void setOffset( int o ) {
        off = o;
        update();
    }
};
```

The main :

```
int main( int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    Labels l;
    l.show();

    /* Animated the view */
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(&l,"offset");
    animation->setLoopCount( -1 ); /* infinite loop */
    animation->setDuration(2000);
    animation->setStartValue(0.0);
    animation->setEndValue(200.0);
    animation->start();
    return app.exec();
}
```

The hardest thing is to calculate the max offset...

Comment: I did it similar to this. In my case it wasn't that hard to calculate the max offset, since i'm displaying images of same size, and with equal spacing between them. Thank you.